# Bitbake - non debug package contains .debug directory

Tags: linux, bitbake, openembedded

I need to create a .ipk package from Bitbake script. My bb file:

```
...
PR = "r0"
PACKAGES = "${PN}"

SRC_URI = " \
    file://mypackage \
    file://mypackage-startup \
"

do_install() {
    install -m 0775 -d ${D}/userdata/costume
    install -m 0744 ${WORKDIR}/mypackage ${D}/userdata/costume/mypackage
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/mypackage-startup ${D}/userdata/costume/mypackage-startup
}

FILES_${PN} += "/userdata/costume"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "/userdata/costume/.debug"

...
```

But I receive the next error:

> ERROR: QA Issue with mypackage: non debug package contains .debug
>   directory: mypackage path
>   /work/.../mypackage-1.0-r0/packages-split/mypackage/userdata/costume/.debug/mypackage
>   FATAL: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them. ERROR:
>   Error in executing python function in:
>   /home/nickname/build/mypackage.bb ERROR:
>   Exception: Message:1 ERROR: Printing the
>   environment of the function ERROR: Function do_package_qa failed
>   ERROR: TaskFailed event exception, aborting ERROR: Build of
>   /home/nickname/build/mypackage.bb do_package failed

Line with `FILES_${PN}-dbg` was added after net surfing. But this fix not helped in my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `PACKAGES = "${PN}"` which means the debug package is never created (the default value of PACKAGES does contain ${PN}-dbg).

Either remove the PACKAGES line (if you didn't have a good reason for it) or use

```
PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}"
```